# SQL Logical "AND" operator

Tags: sql, wordpress, select, operators

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
WHERE (meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value LIKE $var1) AND (meta_key = 'age' AND meta_value = $var2)
GROUP BY user_id
```

Is this SQL query is correct?

Can I use AND operators like this `(meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value LIKE $var1) AND (meta_key = 'age' AND meta_value = $var2)`?

Comment: you have error?

Comment: It will always return 0 rows.  `meta_key` cannot be equal to 'first_name' **and** to 'age' at the same time.  Plus your `GROUP BY` without aggregation does not make sense.

Comment: Query doesn't work for me. If i change 1 AND operator to OR then it works. Like this `(meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value LIKE $var1) OR (meta_key = 'age' AND meta_value = $var2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `and` logical operator. However, the `where` clause applies to each row individually, so it won't achieve the result you're trying to get. One way to handle such issues is to have several conditions in the `where` clause and use a `having` clause to check how many of these are met:

```
SELECT   user_id 
FROM     $wpdb->usermeta 
WHERE    (meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value LIKE $var1) OR
         (meta_key = 'age' AND meta_value = $var2)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key, meta_value) = 2
```

Mandatory comment: Writing code like this may leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of variable substitution.